# MySql Not Like Regexp?

Tags: mysql, regex, numeric

I'm trying to find rows where the first character is not a digit.  I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(action) FROM actions 
WHERE qkey = 140 AND action NOT REGEXP '^[:digit:]$';
```

But, I'm not sure how to make sure it checks just the first character...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your current regex will match values consisting of *exactly one digit*, not the first character only. Just remove the `$` from the end of it, that means "end of value". It'll only check the first character unless you tell it to check more.

`^[:digit:]` will work, that means "start of the value, followed by one digit".

Answer (score 27):

First there is a slight error in your query. It should be:

```
NOT REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]'
```

Note the double square parentheses. You could also rewrite it as the following to avoid also matching the empty string:

```
REGEXP '^[^[:digit:]]'
```

Also note that using REGEXP prevents an index from being used and will result in a table scan or index scan. If you want a more efficient query you should try to rewrite the query without using REGEXP if it is possible:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(action) FROM actions 
WHERE qkey = 140 AND action < '0'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT(action) FROM actions 
WHERE qkey = 140 AND action >= ':'
```

Then add an index on (qkey, action). It's not as pleasant to read, but it should give better performance. If you only have a small number of actions for each qkey then it probably won't give any noticable performance increase so you can stick with the simpler query.